# Unable to edit ckeditor - access denied

Tags: wysiwyg, users

I have just set up a very simple site with only Drupal 7 core and a couple of other modules. I just installed [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module and given permission to administer access and change ckeditor appearance, but any change I try to make results in an `"access denied 403"` message.

Any help welcomed.

Comment: Clear cache? Rebuild permissions? But perhaps it is a file permissions related issue?

Comment: Tried both clear cache and rebuild permissions, no joy. ... also deleted and reinstalled ckeditor module.....

Comment: Do you use drush? Or module install page? Or manually dl and unpack to folder? Does it require other components to be downloaded such as libraries; have you checked file permissions for these? Really sounds like file permissions related... Drush the most reliable and handy way to install modules and other stuff.

Comment: It turned out that the problem only occurred on my"live" site not local ones on my laptop, and was an issue at my hosting ISP:  see their answer... 

"It seems that the Plugin (module) is running into one of our mod security rules:
Specifically mod security detected an MSSQL code execution and information gathering attempt.

We can disable the rule for you on that specific domain (Or for your entire account) Disabling the account will leave that specific website vulnerable to that specific sort of attack.

Please let us know."      So problem solved for me.